# On affirming life

Tags: dharma, life

I have good understanding of Advaita and Kashmir Shaivism but I'm specifically looking for verses from Puranas or anywhere else which informs an individual on the importance of affirming life.

I'm spending a lot time in creating awareness among friends and people I know on the rising adharma in India. It is very hard for me to ignore. I'm ignoring my real interests of spirituality and reading scriptures.

I vaguely remember Swami Vivekanada telling that the world doesn't need you to save it in the Vol. 1 of Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be a good example.

The Markandeya is probably one of the oldest Puranas in Hinduism.
The text opens with the Mimamsa founder Jaimini asking sage Markandeya for answers to some questions raised by the Mahabharata, but never addressed in it. The Devi Mahatmya, literally "glorification or praises of the Goddess", constitutes chapters 81 to 93 of the Markandeya Purana.

The Devi Mahatmya opens with the legend of King Suratha, who was defeated in battle & exiled, and Samadhi, a merchant who was driven away by his wives & children for his wealth. Once, they meet in the forest.Nevertheless, asserts the text, the two discover that they both care about the welfare of those who drove them out.They wonder why they still care. They meet sage Medhas (Sumedha) for answers. The sage replies that this is the nature of existence, just watch the hungry birds who collect seeds, and despite being hungry those birds drop the seeds into the beaks of their babies. This is the power of the Goddess, her manifestation in nature and everywhere, one who empowers attachments, yet also empowers release

> The Rajah asked, "why do i love those sons and that wife, through whose avarice i am banished?"The Rajah continued , "O divine personage! I am desirous to ask one thing from thee, explain it to me, my mind has lost its function, I am troubled with anxiety? O excellent Muni! what is this? though conscious of transitoriness, yet like an ignorant person I love my kingdom, and all my retinue. He was banished by his son, wife, attendants, and his relations, yet he feels pity for them. In this manner we both excessively grieve, love draws us unto reprehensible actions. What is this, O magnificient sage, though we are ingenious, yet our affection produces cecity in action. The Rishi said, "O great sharer, wisdom exists in all living creatures that are desirous of life, love predominates in each individually. Some animals are blind in the day, others at night, and others again that appear equally blind both day and night. It is true, that kings appear prudent, but are not really so; all the beasts, birds, animals have knowledge. What knowledge mankind is possessed of, the others are equally endowed with. See the birds being wise, though oppressed with hunger themselves, yet lovingly pick up the crumbs with their beaks and feed their young ones? O chief of kings! do you not see men lovingly support their offspring for the benefit of others.By attraction they fall in the vortex of love. By the power of Mahamaya, the world was originally created. Mahamaya seized the lord of the world when at his slumber yoga; the great illusion enveloped Hari, she shackles the world.The divine goddess possesses irresistibly the heart of even the wisest, and forcibly leads into great deception. By her the universe consisting of animates and inanimates was created, her blessings procure emancipation.The knowledge of her is the means of supreme salvation; she is eternal and links mortality; she is the supreme goddess over all goddesses.Durga.